# Error: expected ')' before ';' token

Tags: c, for-loop, compiler-errors

I know there are tons of examples of this question, but I cannot figure it out. This is an incredibly simple issue but I'm pulling my hair out over it. At first I thought that it was how I wrote the `for` loop, but after rewriting it and copying it from another file that does compile, I still have the issue. I've looked at the previous lines and cannot find any open `{`, `[`, or `(`. I've swapped out `CHAR_NUM` for `257` and still no dice. I feel bad asking this because I know it's going to be something stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the error:

```
35: error: expected ')' before ';' token
```

Here is the code up to the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tree.h"

#define CHAR_NUM 257

void countChars(int *, FILE *);
void makeTrees(int *, struct tree *);
struct tree *makeQueue(struct tree *);
int arrayFilled(struct tree *);
void findSmallest(struct tree *, struct tree *, struct tree *);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    assert(argc == 3);
    int *charCounts, *bitList;
    FILE *big, *small;
    struct tree *charList, *heap;
    int i;

    assert((charCounts = malloc(sizeof(int) * CHAR_NUM)) != NULL);
    assert((charList = malloc(sizeof(struct tree) * CHAR_NUM)) != NULL);
    assert((big = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL);
    assert((small = fopen(argv[2], "wb")) != NULL);

    while (i = 0; i < CHAR_NUM; i++) //This is the line with the error
    {
        charCounts[i] = 0;
    }
...
```

Comment: IT'S BEEN SOLVED BY PaulG and Tripp Kinetics. I wrote a `while` instead of a `for` and didn't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the format of a `for` loop not a `while` loop. You want the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < CHAR_NUM; i++) //This is the line with the error
{
    charCounts[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is easily the dumbest thing I've done. Thank you.

Comment: @Bluesroo Happens to all of us once in a while, I'm pretty sure I've done dumber than that at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `while` on that line with `for`.

Comment: This is easily the dumbest thing I've done. Thank you.